# Changing character encoding for embedded Vaadin application

Tags: character-encoding, vaadin, xs

I need to embed Vaadin app in a third party web page.
Web server and application server are in different domains.
Due to the nature of the application, using iframe is not an option. So I used VaadinXS add-on and embeded application inside a div.

Now my problem is:

Web page has non utf encoding (actually it is windows-1251).
And Vaadin servlet default encoding seems to be utf-8.

The question:

Is there a way to override character encoding for Vaadin embedded XS servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone will face the same problem. I found a solution. View it [here](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1225769)